I'm trying to build a mining web app just like Bondex, my tech stack is Nextjs, Zustand, Nextjs API. Tips and overview on how to go about it, please
I'm trying to build a mining web app just like Bondex, my tech stack is Nextjs, Zustand, Nextjs API. Tips and overview on how to go about it, please. It has to be persisted and when the user leaves the site, it should not reset
i tried using cron jobs but it was not effeective
